# Is it possible to concatenate 3D matrices in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

Lets say I have two matrices `A` and `B` that are 3D. `A` is `420x420x3` and `B` is `420x420x3`. After concatenation I want to obtain `C` that is `420x420x6` as the concatenation of `A` and `B` in the third dimension.

How would I do that at matlab ?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`cat`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html):

```
C = cat(3, A, B);
```

Best,

Comment: The best answers are short and sweet. +1.

Comment: Indeed, the shorter the better !